# Nesting the datalist 'option' inside the 'div' shows "Element 'option' cannot be nested inside element 'div'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

The code works fine but I want better approach which will not throw any warning or error to look code more clean.
Is there any way other than putting the `option` inside the `div`.

I am able to accomplish this by using the `id` of  `datalist`. 
But, there are alot of the `datalist` for countries, cities, zones, etc. and it is not better to use the `id` of each `datalist` to bind the data to datalist.

Is there any efficient approach other than using `id` of the `datalist`? So, that I can reuse the same code for each datalist.

```
<input id="input-id" list="datalist-id" type="text" placeholder="Select Cluster Group" autocomplete="off" />
<datalist id="datalist-id">
    <div ng-repeat="country in Countries">
        <option> {{country.name}} </option>
    </div>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `div` and place the `ng-repeat` code inside the `option`.
Refer modified code as below:

```
<input id="input-id" list="datalist-id" type="text" placeholder="Select Cluster Group" autocomplete="off" />
<datalist id="datalist-id">
    <option ng-repeat="country in Countries" value="{{country.name}}" /> 
</datalist>
```